# Is my understanding of the relationship between virtual addresses and physical addresses correct?

Tags: operating-system, memory-address, page-tables

I've been researching (on SO and elsewhere) the relationship between virtual addresses and physical addresses. I would appreciate it if someone could confirm if my understanding of this concept is correct.

The page table is classified as 'virtual space' and contains the virtual addresses of each page. It then maps to the 'physical space', which contains the physical addresses of each page.

A wikipedia diagram to make my explanation clearer:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Virtual_address_space_and_physical_address_space_relationship.svg

Is my understanding of this concept correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely correct.

Each program has its own virtual address space. Technically, there is only one address space, the physical random-access memory. Therefore it's called "virtual" because to the user program it seems as if it has its own address space.

Now, take the instruction `mov 0x1234, %eax` (AT&T) or `MOV EAX, [0x1234]` (Intel) as an example:

1. The CPU sends the virtual address `0x1234` to one of its parts, the MMU.
2. The MMU obtains the corresponding physical address from the page table. This process of adjusting the address is also lovingly called "massaging."
3. The CPU retrieves the data from the RAM location the physical address refers to.

The concrete translation process depends heavily on the actual architecture and CPU.

Comment: My apologies; I forgot to ask a related question before accepting your answer. With regards to 3, would I be correct in saying that the CPU could also retrieve the data from secondary storage, assuming that is where the physical address refers to?

Comment: @handler'shandle No. The CPU can only address primary storage directly. Secondary storage is "addressed" by a controller, which, together with a driver, loads the data from secondary storage to primary storage. Then, the CPU can access it. On the x86 architecture, paging can be used: if the virtual address passed to the MMU doesn't have a corresponding physical memory address in the page table and an appropriate flag is set, secondary storage is consulted and data from there is copied into primary storage.This allows a program to address more addresses than primary storage provides.

Answer (score 0):

> The page table is classified as 'virtual space' and contains the virtual addresses of each page. It then maps to the 'physical space', which contains the physical addresses of each page.

This is not really correct. The page table defines a logical address space consisting of pages. The page table maps the logical pages to physical page frames they indicate that the page frame does not [yet] exist in memory in which case you have a virtual mapping. A page is VIRTUAL when memory is simulated using disk space.

In the olde days, page tables always established a virtual address space. Now it is becoming increasingly common (e.g. embedded system) to use logical address translation without virtual memory (paging). Thus, the terms "virtual memory" and "logical memory" are frequently conflated.

The physical address space exists only to the operating system. The process sees only a logical address space.

That is a bit of an oversimplification because the process becomes the operating system after an exception or interrupt and the kernel operates within a common logical address range. However, the operating system kernel does have to manage physical memory to some degree.

For example, some aspect of the page tables must use physical addresses. If the page tables used all logical addresses, then you'd have a chicken and egg problem for address translation. Various hardware systems address this problem in different ways.

Finally, the diagram you link to is a very poor illustration.